# Помогите подобрать accent color Material Design

Tags: android, material-design

Светлая тема

```
<color name="colorPrimaryLT">#ff1e88e5</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDarkLT">#1976D2</color>
```

Темная тема

```
<color name="colorPrimaryDT">#256E93</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDarkDT">#1A4C66</color>
```

Помогите подобрать accent color для этих двух тем, а то у меня с этим видимо проблемы :) .
И скажите , по какому алгоритму подбираете , пожалуйста

Comment: такой сайт не [пойдёт](https://www.materialpalette.com/)?

Comment: Был там уже. Там нельзя указать в точности , такие цвета как у меня ...

Comment: вот, спрашивают [о том же](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/37520). и ответы есть.

Comment: ок, спасибо, посмотрим

Answer (score 2):

```
 #FF5252
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 #B6B6B6
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(я на сайте http://www.materialpalette.com/ вставлял ваши цвета, меняя хтмл, а потом выбирал наиболее подходящий по собственным соображениям)

Comment: #FF5252 - точно такой и я подобрал, оказывается :)